# How Encrypt module actually works?

Tags: security

I installed the Drupal [Encrypt](https://www.drupal.org/project/encrypt) module and enabled it. However, I wonder how this module actually works. Does it encrypt all the submissions from the browser that the user/admin key in like 1) Login  2) Add/update node  3) Contact form/webform and decrypted again in the server before saving to the database ? Any tool to test this process? I'm looking a way to protect all the submissions or update over the internet which may be captured or exposed especially in the public area when using those free Wi-Fi. Please advise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Encrypt module:

> provides an application programming interface (API) for performing two-way data encryption. It allows modules to encrypt data such that it can be decrypted using the same key that was used to encrypt the data. This is useful for **storing sensitive information**.

Emphasis mine. That's its purpose, to provide an API that other modules can use to encrypt data before it's stored in the database (or elsewhere I guess).

As an API module, it provides no functionality unless you make explicit use of it; either by installing one of the modules listed that uses it, or by writing a custom module that does so. The emphasis is on you (or the writer of a contrib module) to actually do something useful with this module:

> It is up to the module calling encrypt() to manage and store the encrypted data.

The important thing to understand is that it doesn't (and couldn't) protect users from having their data sniffed over a public network. For that you'll need to use HTTPS, no exceptions. All this module does is offer an encryption/decryption service for your server-side app.

Comment: I see..Thanks for your explanations. I thought it's kind of all in one solution. It's actually all different things. Much to learn still. Thanks again !